# SpringBoot, run a daemon as CommandLine (JAR) and inside Tomcat (WAR)?

Tags: spring, web-applications, spring-boot, war

I want to create a  Java deamon process (MQ processor) which can be run both from the commandline (java -jar ...) but also as WAR inside a JEE Container like Tomcat. It should automatically start once the WebApp starts. This App is not going to have a WebGUI.

It seems that I can use **SpringBoot** for this. SpringBoot can both create WAR and JAR-files.

My question is: should I use SpringBoot `ApplicationRunner` for a portable daemon?

**What is the best practice/recipe to create a portable (CLI/WebApp) daemon process with SpringBoot?**

How does this work under the hood? If I use ApplicationRunner and create a WAR, does SpringBoot create a **Servlet** of this?

Tx

Answer (score 0):

`ApplicationRunner` is new in Spring Boot 1.4. It is similar to `CommandLineRunner` of Spring Boot 1.3. It isn't involved in the wiring up of the Application context as such that interface wouldn't be responsible for creating any Servlets in the WAR deployment. Here is details on deploying your app as a WAR:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

The `SpringBootServletInitializer` is what will create the servlet.

Now I am not sure how you are setting up the MQ processor but if it is wired up as a bean and has some listener thread for messages on a queue then you don't really need the `ApplicationRunner`. You would just need to wire up the processor as a bean and have a `@PostConstruct` annotation on it so that you can start the listener thread. If you don't have control of the annotations on the bean then you can use the `ApplicationRunner` and have it `Autowired` with the processor bean. The runner would then start up the listener thread.